# How do you craft trapdoors in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Trapdoors are now available in Minecraft - what is the crafting recipe to make them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A hatch, or trapdoor, is created by filling the bottom and middle rows of the crafting table with wooden planks, like so (image from the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hatch)):

[image]

Comment: Hm. Apparently our browsers use different fonts.

Comment: I noticed that :P. I think it's a "Macs favour Helvetica" thing.

Comment: A sideways door.  Go figure.  :-)

Answer (score 8):

The minecraft wiki calls them trapdoors.

Like doors or ladders, water cannot flow through them, even when open, though it's unclear if Notch will eventually add in this functionality.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trapdoor

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the XB360 and XBONE, PS3, PS4, and Wii U versions of these games, while crafting, you'll usually find trapdoor underneath the door icon, but you need 6 planks to do so!

Answer (score -2):

A hatch (or trapdoor) functions as a horizontal door over a single block hole. It can be activated by right-clicking it or with redstone wire. It is crafted by placing a wooden plank in each of the bottom six slots of a 3x3 crafting grid.

Comment: Okay, listen up: [Self-Promoting is frowned upon](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion). It's also not in your favor that that website has Google Ads on it, many Google Ads spammers have gone down the drain (actually, it's one of the main factors I identify link-spammers upon). Despite that, your answer is on-topic and good, the only reason I see for the downvotes is the fact that you're a promotion-user (or at least sure look like one).

Comment: The guy claims his affiliation right in his user name and the meat of the answer is on this site, so I see nothing to moderate here. (Just saying.)

Comment: Though there is something to be said for his site being outdated (compared to the wiki, at least as of this comment).